# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 by using Laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

I am learning to code using a PHP framework which is laravel to do a chat application from this youtube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sXmfwnxfjA&list=PLJpBh2VJhy5x2GKfkfIcn0r6P6uLat7xR&index=1
but I faced an issue to retrieve the contact list in the video, 17.09. 
I could not get any source online and hope someone could help me by giving me some advice regarding this issue.

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-app">
        <Conversation :contact ="selectedContact" :messages="messages"/>
        <ContactsList :contacts="contacts"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Conversation from'./Conversation';
    import ContactsList from'./ContactsList';

    export default {
        props:{
            user:{
                type:Object,
                required: true
            }           
        },
        data(){
            return{
                selectedContact: null,
                messages:[],
                contacts:[]
            };
        },
        mounted(){
            console.log(this.user);
            axios.get('/Contacts')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.contacts = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
</script>

Console Log Output: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (app.js:699)
    at settle (app.js:960)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:168)
```

Comment: You need to post the sample of the javascript code where you implemented the fetch/ajax request to the URL that returns 404.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, include it as text in your post.